# How to customize form styled by django-uni-form?

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms

I'm using django-uni-form to style my form using the filter my_form|as_uni_form:

```
<form class="uniForm" id="my_form" method="post" action="./">
      <fieldset class="inlineLabels">
           {{ my_form|as_uni_form }}
           <div  class="form_block">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
           </div>
       </fieldset>
</form>
```

It looks really good. But I need to customize it.

For example, one of the field "percentage" of the form is of the type IntegerField. It is being rendered as an `<input type="text">`. The problem is that the text box is really wide, I'd like to make it only 2 character wide. Also I want to add a percentage sign "%" right after the text box so that users know they if they put in the number "10" in the text box, it means 10%.

Is there anyway to do that with django-uni-form?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop over the elements of your form and render the uniForm markup yourself.  Either that, you can customize the look of each input based on an id or class.

What I'd do is look at the mark up it generates, and then loop over the elements generating that same markup and customize them.  See [the Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question as yours. I think the length of the text input is easy to change via css. I'm more concerned about the custom html element behind the input, in your case percentage mark. I don't find an easy solution to it. Looks like either we have to mimick the way a field is rendered in django-uni-form template or write a filter of our own. I'm still waiting for a more elegant solution.